# Angular 4 Dynamically Update Component View?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make an Angular component using moment.js that shows the current time.

I use ngOnInit() to set the current time on initialization, then use the function updateTime() to try and update the time property displayed in the html.

I have a console.log to show the time updating works as planned, but I'm not sure how to display the updated string on the view. It currently remains static after the ngOnInit().

Please help me understand what I have to do to make this function properly.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-time',
  templateUrl: './time.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time.component.css']
})

export class TimeComponent implements OnInit {

  time: any;

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var moment = require('moment');
    this.time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
    this.updateTime();
  }

  updateTime() {
    var moment = require('moment');
    setInterval( function() {
      var now = moment();
      this.time = now.format('h:mm:ss a');
      console.log(this.time);
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

Comment: If you are using the `function` keyword, `this` won't be what you expect. Use `setInterval(() => {` arrow function syntax instead

Comment: that was it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cant be used in the setInterval function scope.

set it up like so:

```
setInterval(() => {
  let now = moment();
  this.time = now.format('h:mm:ss a');
  console.log(this.time);
}, 1000);
```